# Is there anyway to console.log in webpack production?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I enabled webpack production, but I need to check if a function is being called with a console.log. Any way to re-enable it?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is not being removed by webpack. If you uglify the code, unused functions, or unreachable code in general, will be removed from the bundle. They would not have been called anyway, so there is no difference in the output you see.